# Where the members/methods of inner class, static nested class and local inner class are stored.

Tags: java, nested, inner-classes

Is there any difference in how JVM is allocating space to inner class members and methods.
Please provide what is the difference in this context to all the available kinds of nested classes(static,local,non-static,anonymous).
I searched from various other sources but could not get the clear idea.

Comment: What do you mean by stored ?

Comment: resides or allocated inside main memory not related to perm. storage

Comment: Why do you want to know that? It's most likely up to the JVM you use (oracle, open jdk, .. version 5, 6, 7..). For the purpose of programming Java it should be safe to assume that there is no difference.

Comment: just for any mad interviewer. just in brief of heap and stack will be enough.

Comment: THe classes definition are stored in PermGen, as the nested class (inner static) are treated as normal class then they should be stored there too. The inner class and local class that are part of class they belong is would be not natural store in different space. I can not provide for you a prove but Permament generation could be the right place. This apply to Java <= 7 as inn 8 htere is not permgen

Answer (score 1):

The static data members of a class are stored with the class, and the non-static data members in each instance. It doesn't make any difference whether the class itself is static, nested, inner, or anonymous.

The *methods*, whether static or non-static, are stored with the class, again regardless of whether the class itself is static, nested, inner, or anonymous.

Comment: It means non-static are stored in heap area whether or not enclosed class has non static members?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference either whether the class has enclosed classes that are static, inner, or anonymous. I don't understand why you're even asking, or how you think it could possibly make a difference. It's simple. Don't complicate things that aren't complicated. All you need to know is the first sentence of my answer. Forget everything else.